# What is this plane shown on the 'Blended wing body' Wikipedia page?

Tags: military, aircraft-identification, blended-wing

[image]
([wikimedia.org](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:BWB_Composite.jpg) via [wikipedia.org](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blended_wing_body#Characteristics))

What is the second plane from left, between the 757 and the B-2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its a [Rockwell B-1 Lancer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rockwell_B-1_Lancer) a heavy bomber used by the USAF.

[image]

([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rockwell_B-1_Lancer))

Comment: Thanks, Dave! Wikipedia refers to the B-1 as a "variable-sweep wing" aircraft, which would mean that is definitely not a "blended wing body" aircraft, right?

Comment: @CCC being a variable-sweep wing does not exclude you from being a blended wing aircraft. I'd say the B-1 has [_" no clear dividing line between the wings and the main body of the craft._](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blended_wing_body)

Comment: Do you know what model specifically by any chance?

Comment: @dalearn there is only one operational model of the B-1, the B-1B. The B-1A existed only as a few prototypes, which were painted in reflective white with a bright blue flash.

Comment: @CCC: Look for a picture with the wings swept back in high-speed cruise configuration. You can definitely see much less of a clear delineation between wings and body, than in the wings swept-forward low-speed configuration.

Answer (score 1):

It is a B-1 bomber, also affectionately referred to as the "Bone".